# Adding A Login Fail Notice

Tags: login

Im using a custom login page using the wp_login_form tag.

I am also using this code below to redirect back to itself if failed login and change the url. How can i add a  here also to show when failed login.

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'my_front_end_login_fail' );
 function my_front_end_login_fail( $username ) {
  $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
   if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ) {
   wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );  
  exit;
 }}
```

Comment: What is the problem? That should be sending your "failed" indicator in `$_GET['login']`. Check for that and print your message.

Comment: Does the print go in the page itself or in the function?

Comment: In the page that you are redirecting _to_.

Comment: Can you help me with exactly what i need to put in the page? im trying but i cant get it to work.